# Generic infers literal type when there is a union and conditional type is involved

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I stumbled upon this imho inconsistant behaviour:

A conditional alone works fine:

```
class FormControl<T> {
  constructor(t:T extends undefined ? never : T) {}
}
const a = new FormControl('');
//    ^? FormControl<string> // OK
```

A union alone works also fine:

```
class FormControl2<T> {
  constructor(t:T|string) {}
}
const b = new FormControl2("");
//    ^? FormControl<string> OK
```

When both union+conditional are combined :

```
class FormControl3<T> {
  constructor(t:T extends undefined ? never : T|string) {}
}
const c = new FormControl3(""); 
//    ^? FormControl<""> // Too narrow :(
```

How could a get the wider `string` infered type in that 3rd case ? I'm looking for the widen inference not specifying each time time the correct type.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD2AnAtgYXgOwC6PiAPACoB80A3gLABQ00wmEOArsFkgBRYBch0ApgA8sfDABMYTMXwBmASwx9R0APzQFANz6JoXaIQCU5AL7UTVehkbQw0ALxq+AdzhI0mHHnYByL-oDc1AD0gbS0AHrK1NSgkDAIKOjYuCAATESklDR0DMysHNyEAD6MiPIA5oZkZmYWVgBGdg7O8W5JeCnsAESd-kEhoRFR5uBQLgnuyQDM6eTUtLW5bIicPPxCIuLQkqIy8ooqDprauuxFJeX6ldXROXSNCs2uiR4gk109AVTBodCDVNRAA)

Comment: Could you [edit] so that there's only one question?  Right now you have that "and how could" second question at the end, which invites answers that target one but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually a bug, or more of a limitation in TS 4.9.

This limitation has now been raised to 3 levels of nestings in TS 5.0.

See [Issue #52620](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52620) on GitHub.

Comment: It appears to be inconsistent about it though. If it were consistent, your first example should have been resolved to `FormControl<''>` as well, right?

Comment: @chris Yeah, it feels inconsistant to me too !

Comment: Well it's a bug ! https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52620 Anders Hejlsberg added it to the 5.0.1 milestone 

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question!

I'm afraid I don't know why this happens despite I've spent way more time than I'd like to admit trying to figure it out.

As per your last question, you can force an string by doing this:

```
const c = new FormControl3("" as string); 
//    ^? FormControl<string>
```

Alternatively, you can also do this:

```
const c = new FormControl3<string>(""); 
//    ^? FormControl<string>
```